# Create object type from reversed enum

Tags: typescript

If I have this `enum`:

```
enum Enum {
  ONE = 1,
  TWO = 2,
  THREE = 3,
}
```

How could I create a type that would be suitable for this object created from `Enum`:

```
const obj: TypeFromEnum = {
    1: Enum[1],
    2: Enum[2],
    3: Enum[3]
}
```

If I assign `Enum` itself as a type (as was suggested in the first comment to this post), I am getting:

> Type "string" is not assignable to type "Enum".

Comment: [`Enum` already _is_ that object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Enum%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20ONE%20%3D%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20TWO%20%3D%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20THREE%20%3D%203%2C%0D%0A%7D). It just has bidirectional mappings instead of unidirectional.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts but how do I assign `Enum` string values to props of `obj`? If I do it the way I have shown in the post, I get `Type "string" is not assignable to type "Enum".`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding... why can't you just use `const obj = Enum`?

Comment: Also that's not the error I get. I get `Type '{ 1: string; 2: string; 3: string; }' is not assignable to type 'typeof Enum'.
  Property 'ONE' is missing in type '{ 1: string; 2: string; 3: string; }'.` when running [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Enum%20%7B%0A%20%20ONE%20%3D%201%2C%0A%20%20TWO%20%3D%202%2C%0A%20%20THREE%20%3D%203%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20obj%3A%20typeof%20Enum%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%201%3A%20Enum%5B1%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%202%3A%20Enum%5B2%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%203%3A%20Enum%5B3%5D%0A%7D)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You assigned `typeof Enum`, I was assigning just `Enum` as a type. `const obj = Enum` does not work because enum has bidirectional mapping and I do not know how to choose the variant of unidirectional `(ONE: 1 or 1: 'ONE')` while at the same type letting typescript infer the type. I tried it with `for..in` and `fromPairs`. In both cases the inferred type was incorrect. For `for..in` the problem was that initial value of `obj` is being assigned as `{}`prior to execution of `for..in`